# What does a declared but uninitialized variable store?

Tags: c++, pointers

For example, if I have:

```
int num;
double num2;
int* ptr;
```

Are these variables just randomly allocated some memory?

Comment: The allocation is not the issue at all.

Comment: I closed the question under the assumption that you are asking *what* the variables store, as written in your title, not *where* the variables are stored, as seemingly indicated in your question body. Please edit your question to clarify if I misunderstood.